# MessageBox from secondary Form makes Main Form go to background/unfocus

Tags: messagebox, lazarus, lost-focus

I cannot get focus back to Main Form after closing Second Form.

When I do this:
(From Main Form) "Form1Main":

```
..
Form2Output.Show;
..
```

From "Form2Output":

```
if (bNoWarnings = False) AND (Pos('-b',sExeOptions)=0)  then
begin
  if Application.MessageBox(PChar('Execute command line?'+ #13#10#13#10 + P.CommandLine), 'Execute?', MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_YESNO) = IDNO then Exit;
end;
```

It would appear Message Dialog 'steals' focus from main form (Form1Main goes to background when closing Form2Output). If I do not show the MessageDlg (conditions not met), the Main Form "refocuses" just fine when closing Form2Output. I am relatively new to Lazarus and any help would be great..

Comment: Your question about AND/OR is a totally separate topic, and should be posted as a separate question. Please edit your post to do that, and remove the 'pascal' and 'object-pascal' tags, as neither apply to your primary question. Sticking to one main topic per question helps keep things from being noisy, and makes them more useful to others in the future. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an `Application.MainForm.BringToFront;` in `OnClose` of the second form. This behaviour is not attributable to Object Pascal, it's a peculiarity of TApplication design of LCL.

Comment: _Application.MainForm.BringToFront; in OnClose_  did work for me.. thanks so much.

Comment: but what if the window that goes to background is not the main form but itself a subform? I experience this problem in may ap..

Comment: @Tarn - Call show on that form, or ask a question if it's more complicated than that.